# How to Access the Client Header Request

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am getting the data from mobile client they are sending data in JSON as well as sending some values as HEADER  to WSO2ESB i am getting normal values using this property

```
<property name="asset" expression="//asset/text()" scope="default"/>
```

but how can i get HEADER in my ESB i am using this property its not not working

```
<property name="username" expression="get-property('transport', 'Accept')"/>
```

how it will work will you revert me as soon as 
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the Header values in Wso2ESb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374343/how-to-access-the-header-values-in-wso2esb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<property name="username" expression="get-property('transport', 'Accept')"/>
```

In this configuration you are trying to assign an http header named 'Accept' to a property named 'username'.

If 'username' is what you want to access from the http headers, it should look like:

```
<property name="some_name_here" expression="get-property('transport', 'username')"/>
```

Comment: its working from curl command side but from my client side its not working its giving null value