# How to access the Header values in Wso2ESb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am using wso2esb when i am getting request from my mobile client i will get as a HEADER .
But the issue is i am unable to access in wso2ESB insequence for further process how can i do this we have any properties for to do this
my config is

```
 <log>
            <property name="faisal" expression="get-property('username')"/>
            <property name="username" expression="get-property('transport', 'Accept')"/>
            <property name="username" expression="//username/text()"/>
            <property name="password" expression="//password/text()"/>
         </log>
```

every thin showing me as null
and the header which is they are sending like this

```
Login {"password":"gbadmin","username":"faisal"}
```

how can i access this into insequence 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If it is coming as a transport header you should be able to access it like follows.

```
<property name="PROPERTY_NAME_HERE" expression="$trp:HEADER_NAME_HERE"/>
```

Replace 'HEADER_NAME_HERE' with your header name.

Answer (score 0):

How is your JSON request looks like?  If your JSON request as given below

{
  "Login": {
    "username": "test",
    "password": "aa"
  }
}

You should be able to access the username information as

```
<property name="username" expression="//Login/username"/>
```

Comment: my request like above i mentioned but it will come as header how could i retrieve it i am trying with this property             <property name="username" expression="get-property('transport', 'Accept')"/> it is giving null